# The average value of f on region R (double integrals)

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, average

If I am given f(x,y) and I calculate the average of the region given by the formula in this [image](http://d2vlcm61l7u1fs.cloudfront.net/media%2Fa30%2Fa307451b-b97e-4969-a1a2-5bcee66c8998%2Fphp3g1Hfa.png) should the average **always**  = (min of f(x,y) +max of f(x,y))/2. I think this is only the case if the shape is uniform, like a rectangle. Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: It is not equal even if the shape is rectangular, consider $f(x,y)=\begin{cases}1 & x=y=0\\0 & \text{else}\end{cases}$ in the region $[-1,1]\times[-1,1]$.

Comment: sorry, I'm still not clear. So you are saying that the average is never exactly between the  min and max values of the function, but that it just falls between the range?

Comment: The average is between the max and min, but the value is given by the integral in your picture, not $\frac{\max+\min}2$.